# Docker w/ PHP-FPM & Nginx - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx, debian, docker, php-fpm

I'm currently trying to dockerise a Laravel application, I've managed to create my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml with the dependencies I need. However, I am struggling to get php-fpm to kick in that will show my application.

**Dockerfile**

```
# Set master image
FROM php:8.0-fpm-alpine

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/html/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Install Additional dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache \
    build-base shadow vim curl \
    php8 \
    php8-fpm \
    php8-common \
    php8-pdo \
    php8-pdo_mysql \
    php8-mysqli \
    php8-mbstring \
    php8-xml \
    php8-openssl \
    php8-json \
    php8-phar \
    php8-zip \
    php8-gd \
    php8-dom \
    php8-session \
    php8-zlib \
    nodejs \
    npm

# Add and Enable PHP-PDO Extenstions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql

# Install PHP Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Remove Cache
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# Add UID '1000' to www-data
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/html

# Change current user to www
USER www-data

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /var/www/html/
RUN npm install
RUN npm run dev

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3'
services:

  #Laravel App
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: heychazza/joinservers.com
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    expose:
      - "9000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - mynet

  #Nginx Service
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./deployment/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
      #- ./nginx/ssl/:/etc/nginx/ssl/
    depends_on:
      - app
    networks:
      - mynet

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "33060:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laraveldb
      MYSQL_USER: laravel
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: laravelpassworddb
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpasswordmysql
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql/
    networks:
      - mynet

#Docker Networks
networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  mysqldata:
    driver: local
```

What am I doing? I'm running Docker from a MacBook, and are looking to deploy this onto a production Debian machine.

I'm still new to docker, so apologies if I've missed anything out.

Comment: What is the nginx configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Solved, turns out I needed to change the php location to.

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index            index.php;
        fastcgi_pass             app:9000;
        include                  fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```